# Tor exit node is Forum spammer

Tags: exit-relays, circuit

When I researched the exit node for the tor circuit I was given, I saw that it was a forum spammer. Even after changing my identity , the new exit node was still listed as a forum spammer. Is this common with tor or dangerous ? I was using the Tor browser for linux.

Comment: Where were you looking? If somebody maintains a list of IP addresses that are known "forum spammers", then one of the things they probably did was import the entire list of Tor exit IP addresses, and call them all forum spammers. Because that's a common thing and happens all the time.

Comment: It was on myipaddress.com . Not sure it's a trusted source. There were comments saying they were used for creating spamming forum bots.

Comment: Well, it's probably true. People use Tor for all kinds of unsociable things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tor relays which allow exiting can be used for forum spamming, as such they are often added to generic "blacklists" regardless of any actual abuse having occurred.

This is just the nature of blacklisting and it's not dangerous to you personally while using Tor, however you may find it inconvenient. This is the price of anonymity, you are indistinguishable from spammers (without further verification, e.g. a captcha-based solution).